# How does ArcMap calculate the default cell size when rectifying a raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, georeferencing

When rectifying a raster, there is an option to enter a cell size. I was wondering how ArcMap calculates this default cell size, particularly in relation to the raster's resolution.

Comment: @yanes I think you should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember needing this for a paper,

“The default cell size is the shortest of the width or height of the extent of the input feature dataset, in the output spatial reference, divided by 250” (ESRI, 2010)

Ref:
ESRI. (2010). ArcMap (Version 10.0). Redlands, CA: Environmental Systems Research Institute. [ESRI](http://www.esri.com/), Accessed 2011 May 02.
Sorry I don't have the exact link but you can search it on their site.

Comment: no problem, glad that it helped you, if you happened to get the direct link please post it here.

Comment: Found it on the ArcGIS Desktop Help. http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000002v000000